# Does the DataSnapshot returned by adding a listener to a query differ to that of one added directly to a DatabaseReference

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, listener

This is a broad question about the difference between running a query on Firebase data vs accessing the data without using the query class.

Here is the structure of a query, taken from the docs and trimmed down a bit:

```
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Users");

Query exampleQuery = myRef.orderByChild("age");

exampleQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            // Do something...

        }
    }
});
```

Looking at it and reading that one has to increment over the DataSnapshot, lead me to wonder if it differed to the DataSnapshot retured in the below example, and if not, is it correct to think of the query class as nothing more than an intermediary to add sorting and filtering to the data before working with it, and hence fine to add a for loop when not using the query class, as in the below example?

```
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Users");

myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            // Do something...

        }
    }
});
```

I realise that this question may seem trivial, but I have not come across examples of a for loop being used when the query class is not, hence me wanting to confirm that the two are not tied together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference). You will find

```
public class DatabaseReference extends Query
```

which means every methods of the class `Query` are also inherited to class `DatabaseReference`.

> Does the DataSnapshot returned by adding a listener to a query differ to that of one added directly to a DatabaseReference?

**No, they are the same unless the references are not different.**

> Where to use `Query` then?

I believe the `Query` class is usually used to filter the results and if you have multiple queries to do.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40314486/how-to-sort-in-the-new-firebase-database-reference-recyclerview) too. `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` needs and only accepts an instance of `Query` class not the `DatabaseReference`.